# Blazor WASM standalone project reauthentication for multiple browser tabs after logout

Tags: authentication, logout, blazor-webassembly, session-state

I have implemented authorization with JWT auth on our blazor WASM project. All was well - logging in and logging out...until

**Scenario:**
I noticed that if I duplicated my 'logged in (authenticated identity user) tab', now having two valid authorized user tabs open. In the first tab I log out: I am re-directed to the login page, the stored token is gone, everything seems ok - but when I go to the second tab and click to go to a new page(within the tab) I am able to do so. When I debug and check the auth state.. it still has the validated identity user!

**Expected Results:**
When I logout in the first autenticated tab, I expect the auth state of the second tab to also be deauthenticated.

**Error Messages:**

Currently none

**What I have tried:**

I searched around for someone solving the same thing for Blazor WASM standalone apps. I did come across this guy's video where he describes most people are using the AuthenticationStateProvider wrong by injecting it directly instead of using a cascading parameter. He actually then demonstates the exact issue I am having - but then proceeds to solve it with a Balzor Server class library(using RevalidateServerAuthenticationStateProvider with some custom code on the ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync function)! Not a WASM solution! Link to his video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42O7rECc87o&list=WL&index=37&t=952s - 13:23 he demonstrates the issue I have attempted to depict.

**Code of my logout sequence:**

To start - when you click the logout button - I redirect to a logout page. We will start here:

*Logout.Razor.cs*

```
[CascadingParameter]
    public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await AuthService.Logout();
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
    }
```

You can see you then are waiting for the AuthService to log you out.

*AuthService.cs*

```
 private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;

 public async Task Logout()
    {
        await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("authToken");
        await ((CustomAuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserLogout();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
    }
```

Then you are waiting on the CustomAuthStateProvider:AuthenticationStateProdiver to notify that the state has changed.

*CustomAuthStateProvider.cs*

```
 _anonymous = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

 public async Task NotifyUserLogout()
    {           
        var authState = Task.FromResult(_anonymous);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
```

At this point in the active page we are logged out and redirected to the login page.
I was hoping there is some browser session option for the authstate I am missing or there is some microsoft documentation of handling this situation on WASM projects - but my peanut brain can't seem to find it.

**Additional Information:** I am purely only using the AuthenticationStateProdiver for a custom login.
I am not using OidcAuthentication or MsalAuthentication services.
This is a standlone WASM app with a completely decoupled API. All .net6 living on azure.

Looking forward to see if anyone else has this issue!

BR,

MP